# Function name to find number of rows & columns of a file

Tags: r

I need to find number of rows & columns of a text file?
I have used a function to find it.
eg: I have a text file 'test' with 20 rows & 10 columns.
How do I find the number of rows & columns of the file 'test'?

Comment: I think you just want the `dim()` function. It would be more clear if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and described exactly what the desired output is.

Comment: Did you try searching for this first? I typed "number of rows for text file in R" into google and [the first link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/easy-way-of-determining-number-of-linesrecords-in-a-given-large-file-using-r/) had a very nice answer.

Comment: Thank you Guys. New to R :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the example reproducible.

I took the question to mean "making your own function" which would be solved by the following example

```
lengthFunc <- function(filePath){

df<-read.csv(filePath)

df<- data.frame(df)
return(c(nrow(df), ncol(df))
}


testRead <- lengthFunc(filePath)

Numrow<- testRead[1]
Numcols <- testRead[2]
```

Using  MrFlick's comment you could do the following

```
dataFrame <- data.frame(read.csv(pathName))
```

rows would be given by

```
dim(dataFrame)[1]
```

columns:

```
dim(dataFrame)[2]
```